# How would I write this LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a set of records. The records are ordered by year.

```
Record
{
  string Name {get;set;},
  int Year {get;set;}
  //some other properties
}
```

I have a set of rules that run against each record. Each rule has a type and a condition.

```
Rule
{
  RuleType Type {get;set;},
  Func<Record,bool> Condition {get;set;}
}
```

For a given rule type, I want to iterate through the list of records and find the first time that rule condition was met. I want to do this for all rule types.

If I were writing this in SQL, I might write it something

```
SELECT Type, MIN(Year) 
FROM Records, Rules
WHERE Rules.Condition(Records) = TRUE
GROUP BY Type
```

In LINQ, I'm struggling to correctly put together the Cartesian join + a single where condition + first occurrence + a grouping.

Please assist.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the connection between `Record` and `Rule`? Can you provide an example list?

Comment: It would be ideal to show example information and an example result.  You want the first occurrence per group?

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Calculate MIN(Year) */
var rule = rules.First(r => r.Type == specificType);
var result = records
    .Where(r => rule.Condition(r))
    .Min(r => r.Year)

/* or just some other rule */

var result = records.FirstOrDefault(r => rule.Condition(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a Cartesian Product in linq query syntax using a double `from` like this:

```
var query= from r in Records
           from rule in Rules
           where rule.Condition(r)
           group new {rule.Type, r.Year } by rule.Type into g
           select g.OrderBy(e=>e.Year).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You meant `rule.Type`, not `r.Type`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two sequences. A sequence of Records and a sequence of Rules:

```
IEnumerable<Record> records = ...
IEnumerable<Rule> rules = ...
```

Your textual description of your goal is a bit different than your sql statement suggests:

> For a given rule type, I want to iterate through the list of records and find the first time that rule condition was met. I want to do this for all rule types.

In other words: for every rule you only want the first record that matches the rule.

Your SQL statement suggests you want for every rule all records that meet the rule, ordered by record year

**Your textual requirements.** For this your LINQ would be like:

```
IEnumerable<Record> result = Rules.Select(rule =>
    records.Where(record => rule.Condition(record))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In words: from every rule in the sequence of rules, take the first (or default) record in the sequence of records where rule.Condition(record) is true.

This is exactly according to the textual description of your goal, however, from the resulting sequence of records you only know for every record there is a rule where the record meets the rule. You don't know anymore for which rule the record is the first that meets the condition.

If you also want to know to which rule this first record matches, remember the rule in your result:

```
var result = rules.Select(rule => new
    {
        Rule = rule,
        FirstMatchingRecord = records
        .Where(record =>rule.Condition(record))
         .FirstOrDefault(),
     });
```

From every rule in the collection of rules select the rule and the first record of the collection of records that matches the rule and put them together in an anonymous object with properties Rule and FirstMachingRecord

Note that each first matching record is in the order of your record collection. Your SQL statement suggests that you want to order the records in ascending year:

```
IEnumerable<Record> result = Rules.Select(rule =>
    records.Where(record => rule.Condition(record))
    .OrderBy(record => record.Year)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Depending on the number of records and the number of matching records it might be wise to first order the records and then use the ordered result in your where statement:

```
var orderedRecords = records.Orderby(record => record.Year);
IEnumerable<Record> result = Rules.Select(rule =>
    orderedRecords.Where(record=> rule.Condition(record))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Your SQL statement** suggests that you want a group of rules with for every rule a sequence of records ordered by year. In linq:

```
var result = rules.Select(rule => new
    {
        Rule = rule,
        MatchingRecords = records
            .Where(record => rule.Condition(record))
            .OrderBy(record => record.Year),
    });
```

For every rule in the collection of rules, make a new anonymous object, that contains the rule, and the sequence of records that match the rule ordered by year in ascending order. From this result